# Find coprime integers that have no primitive roots between 2 and 15.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find integers $a$ and $b$ with gcd($a$, $b$) $= 1$ such that whenever $p$ is an odd prime such that $p \equiv a \ (mod\ b)$, then none of the numbers $2$ through $15$ represent primitive roots in $U_p$.

Having a hard time starting with this one. Any tips?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does $U_p$ mean?

Comment: I think $Z/pZ$ is the same thing, a congruence class I think it's called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key fact: if $g$ is a square modulo $p$ (with $p$ prime, $p\ne2$), then $g$ is not a primitive root.

First, suppose that
$$p\equiv1\pmod8\ .\tag{1}$$
Then (brackets denote Legendre symbols) we have
$$\Bigl(\frac2p\Bigr)=1\ ,$$
so $2$ is a square and hence not a primitive root modulo $p$.  Now we want to find $p$ such that $3$ is a square: since we have already said $p\equiv1\pmod8$, we have
$$\Bigl(\frac3p\Bigr)=1\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \Bigl(\frac p3\Bigr)=1$$
which is true when
$$p\equiv1\pmod3\ .\tag2$$
We can solve $(1)$ and $(2)$ simultaneously by the Chinese Remainder Theorem to see that if
$$p\equiv1\pmod{24}$$
then both $2$ and $3$ are squares, and hence not primitive roots, modulo $p$.

Now continue in the same way.  Two more hints:

- you don't need to look at *every* number from $2$ to $15$;
- a pattern should soon become clear.

Comment: We haven't covered the chinese remainder theorem for this class, but I think I have an idea of how to use it after some googling. Would I want to continue on to find p such that 5 is a square? Would I use that in conjunction with $p \equiv 1 (mod\ 24)$ and the chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: You will find that you only need a specific and very easy (almost obvious) case of the CRT.  Thinking about $5$ next would be a good idea.

Comment: So taking $(\frac{5}{p}) = 1$ which implies $(\frac{p}{5}) = 1$ which is true when $p \equiv 1 (mod\ 5)$ and then using the previous equivalency as well as  $p \equiv 1 (mod\ 3)$, results in $p \equiv 1 (mod\ 15)$. Would I then continue along with the other primes (7, 11, 13) in this manner?

Comment: It seems the pattern is $p \equiv 1 (mod a)$ and $p \equiv 1(mod b)$ results in $p \equiv 1 (mod ab)$, and I can use the legendre symbol to show that each is a square along the way.

Comment: Sounds like you're probably right.  If you can write it up carefully and give accurate proofs, then you will know for sure that you are right.

Comment: Great, Thank you so much!